# How to call a batch file that is on a server?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to script the installation of new computers at my office. I am stuck on one section here:

I need to run this command and I need to run the batch file as an administrator.

start \SERVERNAME\M-Modal\Fluency.Direct.9.1.65.7.6.4.v7\fd.client\install_silent.bat\

how would I change my credentials to tell it to run as an administrator ?

Also, What is the command to call the batch file that is located on this server ?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

```
$cred = get-credential
start-process -credential -cred
```

Enter your admin account in get-credential.

Alternatively

```
Start-Process -FilePath "x.bat" -Verb runAs
```

From Example 5 from here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx

Thanks, Tim.